# Waiting for things is tedious, is there any way to speed up the passage of time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a creative map that uses a lot of vines. Waiting for these to grow naturally is taking a long time, and placing them manually would be a huge amount of effort. Is there anyway to expedite the natural growth of the vines?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't mind installing a mod, because that's what it might take.

Comment: Are you unwilling to simply leave minecraft running while you, say, compete in a strong man competition for a few hours?

Comment: @MBraedley I do not

Comment: @RavenDreamer I would not last even a single hour in a strong man competition.

Comment: place the start of the vines and load the world in a sever (ensure chunks stay loaded through some means some forge mods have chunk loaders like railcraft) and leave running overnight, the server takes less resources to keep running

Comment: How much vine are we talking about here? You can easily just place small amounts. To get it to hang down, make a pillar, cover it in vine, then destroy blocks (expect one that is connected to top vine piece).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a program called [McEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-now-open-source/) to make this map instead of creative mode, it's a lot easier and faster, and you can save sets of blocks as "schematics" for re-use later on.

If you are intent on doing it creative mode, I would say place the vines and go work on another part of the map, giving them time to grow. There is a mod called [Somnia](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1938500-164forgesmp-somnia-simulating-the-world-while-you-sleep/) that simulates the world while you sleep in a bed.

Comment: I can vouch for Somnia - it works great.

Comment: Using MCEdit is not appropriate for this I'm afraid, unless SethBling has made a 'put vines all over this and grow them' filter?

Comment: Does not solve the problem when I need to test something that takes time.

Answer (score 5):

The growth of vines (and other random stuff) is controlled by the so called random ticks, which is part of the regular [block ticks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tick#Block_tick)

> On every game tick, 3 block positions are chosen at random from each section in an area 15 chunks on a side and centered on the player. Any blocks at those positions are given a "random block tick".[1] Most blocks ignore this tick, but **some use it to do something spontaneous: plants grow or die, fire burns out, ice melts, leaves decay, farmland becomes hydrated, and so on**. These ticks are called random ticks.

As of [snapshot 14w17a](https://minecraft.wiki/w/14w17a) or release version 1.8, the number of randomly chosen blocks per game tick can be set using a game rule:

```
/gamerule randomTickSpeed [value]
```

The default value is 3. It can also be set to 0, which means that nothing in the world will ever grow, which can be quite convenient for adventure maps or minigames.

Answer (score -1):

Space the vines out so as to maximize the growth area.  Place vines several blocks apart to allow each one maximum room to expand.  Then as they grow, clip the new growth and move it to an area with no neighboring vines.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the cheapest way to 'speed up' the passage of time.

1. Secure yourself in a well-lit place with a ceiling only 2 blocks high.
2. Open up your inventory
3. Click out of the game and do anything else you want as time passes by in your game.

By doing this, you can trick the game into 'pausing' your character, but not the world around him.  The world will still move at the same speed, so technically you aren't 'speeding up' the passage of time, but by doing this you can completely ignore as much of that time as you like.

Comment: Fredley is in creative, so getting in a secure place isn't necessary. This isn't tricking the game either; it's just waiting for vines to grow, which he wants to avoid doing.

Comment: @colorfusion Creative is another matter, in which case yes, he wouldn't need to worry about securing himself. I'd still recommend this though, for anyone who doesn't want to install a mod and just wants to have their vines grow without having to pace back and forth in-game waiting for them.